# ClassLoaders to load two versions of the same API

Tags: java, classloader

i have to develop an application capable of connect to BusinessObjects 3.1 and 4.2 versions at same time.

Both have a java API, but the 4.2 one is unable to connect to an 3.1 server so i must have the two APIs loaded at same time, but they share package and class names.
Could i acomplish this task with different ClassLoaders?

This is more a theoretical question than a concrete one, as i have never worked with ClassLoaders

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why (and flag this for re-opening in case it is effectively closed). Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked question asks "how do classloaders work" This one is the more specific "how do I load two classes with the same name", which the linked answer hints at but doesn't really get into